# Why is my Event Log Name, Source, and other properties blank?

Tags: powershell, event-log

I am creating an event log with PowerShell using the following command:

```
New-EventLog -LogName "TestLog" -Source "TestLog_Source"
```

The log gets created but all of its properties are blank.

I've tried removing the log and re-running the command and it has not worked.

Log Name: 
Source: 
Event ID: 
Level: 
User: 
OpCode: 
More information: Event Log Online Help

I also notice that the application is not actually logging anything to the log either. The above is what the first column of the event log properties at the bottom shows me. There are other event logs on the server that show those values populated.

Comment: Has anything been written to that eventlog yet? If not, why are you surprised that it's empty?

Comment: Nothing has been written at all. I am surprised because when we start our windows service, it's supposed to write "In onStart" to the event log. 

It works with other services, but not this particular one. 

A little background, we had to remove an old event log because it was using the same source but a different name.

Comment: I meant "was anything supposed to have been written to that eventlog yet?" Apparently that's the case, so you need to show the code that supposedly would write to that eventlog. Also, have you tried manually writing to that eventlog (as the same user)?